# Can't cast LayoutParameters

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

My namespace contains the word `Android`, therefore I have to work around the following problem: I want to change the bottom margin of my `RelativeLayout`.

```
public RelativeLayout RelativeLayout { get; set; }

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams 
= (global::Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)_RelativeLayout.LayoutParameters;
relativeParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);
_RelativeLayout.LayoutParameters = relativeParams;
```

This gives me an `InvalidCastException` right at the first line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `_RelativeLayout`?

Ideally your cast or this safe cast should work:

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = a.LayoutParameters as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;`

Comment: I would change the namespace if possible. Creating a project with Android in the namespace causes so many issues.You will constantly have to be working around them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to change the namespace to something like Droid if it has to contain the platform. Using Android in your namespace will do more harm than anything else because you have to constantly find workarounds for such a tiny change.